# Pure Greedy algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I study pure greedy algorithms in different bases.  I am interested in the following question:  Is there such a [Riesz basis](http://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math772/Fall11/772f11lec11.pdf) $D$ in Hilbert space and $f\in H$ such that
$$
    \|f-G_m(f,D)\| > Cm^{-1/2} |f|_H
$$
for every constant $C$?  In other words, is there a Riesz basis that yields a convergence rate bigger than $-1/2$?

I know that there are such dictionaries whose convergence rate is larger than $-1/2$ (even $-0.27$) but I cannot construct such a Riesz basis.

**Note:** A Pure Greedy Algorithm is defined inductively by
\begin{align*}
  G_0(f) & = 0 \\
  G_m(f) & = G_{m-1}(f)+G(f-G_{m-1}(f))
\end{align*}
where $G(f)=\langle f,g\rangle g$  and $g=g(f)$ is an element from $D$ that maximizes $\left|\langle f,g\rangle\right|$.

Here are some ideas that might be helpful.  It is known that if
$$
    \sup_{g\in D} \sum_{g'\in D,~ g'\ne g} \left|\langle g,g'\rangle\right| < 1/3,
$$
then the convergence rate is less than $-1/2$.  That is why I took Riesz basis for which that supremum is equal to 1:
$$
    D=(f_j), ~\text{where}~ f_j=e_j+\frac{1}{2}e_{j+1}.
$$
Now I want to find $f$. But I can not :(

Some useful information can be found in [this paper by DeVore and Temlyakov](http://mosaic.math.tamu.edu/~rdevore/publications/91.pdf) and [this paper by Temlyakov](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_II/contents/ICM_Vol_2_70.pdf).

Comment: you might want to give some references and define your notation an terminology. i am guessing this link for example is useful: http://mosaic.math.tamu.edu/~rdevore/publications/91.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I have  this paper and I read, but still I have problems

Comment: i meant give references like this paper so that others know what you're talking about

Comment: Edited to correct grammar/readability issues.  Please double-check that I haven't changed the meaning.  What does "PGA" stand for?

Comment: Thanks for editing, meaning haven't changed. "PGA" stands for Pure Greedy Algorithm